# jquery/ GWT for JSP, Java back-end?

Tags: jquery, gwt

Which front-end tool/framework is suitable/practical if you have a JSP, Java back-end?

Jquery or GWT?

just got confusion.
some of my jquery ajax calls won't output a response in the front end.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT can help you to build front end website, it also can build back end serivce.
e.g. You built a web widget with GWT which makes AJAX calls to the GWT service. GWT's output is javascript, HTML and CSS for front end, of course you can utilize some JQuery features within GWT and it can be implemented as native method within Java. For AJAX, GWT has already got a set of features to allow you to make efficient calls to the back end. This provides best performance if you build the back end with GWT service.
On the other hand, you can also use GWT to call the services built by JSP without any problem.

For JSP, I'd stick with JQuery since these two are really independent, it is like JQuery to PHP. In contrast, GWT has more integration done on both ends and it encapsulates something that you might want to learn by yourself.

Comment: thanks. so, it's still GWT that we need to use for back-end. i mean database retrieving,etc?. in our project,we need to use java, & Spring MVC framework. so, would GWT be redundant?

Answer (score 1):

For me, GWT is more suited to "applications", meaning they're one-page.  Like GMail really.  It doesn't work so well with page transitions (imho).

I wrote some thoughts on [Why isn’t Google Web Toolkit more popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523728/why-isnt-google-web-toolkit-more-popular/523759#523759)

I'm a huge fan of jQuery.  I really like the rapid turnaround you can get with jQuery (vs **slow** GWT compiles).

It's hard to give you any particular recommendation though without knowing specifics about your requirements and what you're developing.

Comment: we're just having a thesis project in school, what is required is it is online, and has a Java back-end. its up to us to use what front-end.:)thanks.

Comment: Doesn't really say anything about what the project is though.  Need more information.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how complex the front end is - and how nicely the backend data can be transferred to the front end.

to me, if you have a jsp based app, it would seem like there are plenty of page transitions, and thus gwt isnt quite as good a fit as jquery.

having said that, may be it is possible to not use page transitions, but make the app a single monolithic page with gwt. that way, you might make the user experience better. it really depends on the app tho. if you provided more information about the nature of the app, a better answer can be given.

Comment: what we'll be doing is a online shopping cart with Admin CMS of course, admin can manage shop items, and website style. this is a school project.and it is a requirement to use Java as back-end. so, i am confused which front-end/ajax tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this lately, so I present my thoughts:

GWT is best suited to a web application with complex UI logic. You don't need it if you want to show a simple few page site with minimal interactions. For that GWT is overkill, so use some basic jQuery.

However, **if you need very high UI complexity**, then writing all that JS, unit testing it, and optimizing it for browsers is a major PITA. The strict typing and compilation of GWT will save you from debugging nightmares where some JS type coercion you never thought possible bites you. Of course, you can do things like run Quake in your browser with GWT C++->Java->JS conversion which would be impossible without GWT.

As noted, **compilation times for GWT scale with the size of the site**. If you want 100 screens with 20 browser permutations, it will take a while to build the whole thing, so break that out into several projects. Using this approach and **Super DevMode** you can rebuild in seconds.

A final note: complex JSP sites can be a major pain too. I've been on projects where those 500+ xml/jsp files were a nightmare too, so whatever you do, plan for complexity as it truly limits web apps.